# Properties of the solution of non-linearly separable

Tags: svm

I just learned the basics of SVM, and I have 2 questions about the solution for the non-separable case:

1. In the separable case, the distance of all the support vectors from the hyperplane is the same, and they determine the margin. Now, in the non-separable case, is it possible that no support vector falls on the edge of the margin?
2. In the separable case the meaning of $\frac{1}{\vert \vert \beta \vert \vert}$ was the distance of the support vectors from the hyperplane (where the hyperplane is defined by $\beta ^T x+\beta _0 = 0$). What is the exact meaning of $\frac{1}{\vert \vert \beta \vert \vert}$ in the non-separable case?

Comment: I would suggest you to look at literature that explaining SVN from [hinge loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hinge_loss) persopective